# PHP sending XML URL access different to cURL

Tags: php, curl, soap

I have this URL access : http://bookings.seawings.ae/remoteconnect/default.asp?XML=%3Ccs%3E%0D%0A+%3Co+n%3D%22authenticationcode%22+v%3D%22d657cce7fa320a23950dca157fe693b8%22%2F%3E%0D%0A+%3Cc+n%3D%22flightsearch%22%3E%0D%0A++%3Cq+n%3D%22StartDate%22+v%3D%2211-Apr-2012%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++%3Cq+n%3D%22EndDate%22+v%3D%2211-Apr-2014%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++%3Cq+n%3D%22Typeofflight%22+v%3D%22SILVER%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++%3Cq+n%3D%22Seats_Adult%22+v%3D%228%22%2F%3E%0D%0A+%3C%2Fc%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fcs%3E
and it returns :

```
<cs> <c n="flightsearch"> <q n="XSD" v="system message [QVIEW.NO_ACCESS] Info: No Access [CQV00055.QVIEW.RUN]"/> <q n="XML" v="system message [QVIEW.NO_ACCESS] Info: No Access [CQV00055.QVIEW.RUN]"/> </c> </cs>
```

but when I try to run it in PHP:

```
       <?php $request_xml = '<cs> <o n="authenticationcode" v="d657cce7fa320a23950dca157fe693b8"/> <c n="FlightSearch"> <q n="StartDate" v="1-Jul-2013"/> <q n="EndDate" v="30-Jul-2013"/> <q n="Seats_adult" v="3"/> </c> </cs>';
        $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://bookings.seawings.ae/remoteconnect/default.asp'); 
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_xml); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo stripslashes($result);
        curl_close($ch);
        ?>
```

it only returns: "''"
what part am I doing wrong?

Comment: there are issues in your ssl, why you don't try to curl http instead of https ?

Comment: Hi Sir. I'm a newbie at this. Can you please guide me? I tried changing the https to http on 'https://bookings..' but still not getting same response compared to URL access. Am I missing headers or something?

Comment: instead of using https protocol , `https://bookings .... ` use the only http , `http://bookings ... `

Comment: I've repleaced http from https but I'm getting response - "''" not xml from web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a lot of issues with your code:

this is a quick working example , I'm going to explain what happened there :

```
$request_xml = '<cs> <o n="authenticationcode" v="d657cce7fa320a23950dca157fe693b8"/> <c n="FlightSearch"> <q n="StartDate" v="1-Jul-2013"/> <q n="EndDate" v="30-Jul-2013"/> <q n="Seats_adult" v="3"/> </c> </cs>';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://bookings.seawings.ae/remoteconnect/default.asp');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // if you want to disable printing headers set this to false , or simply remove it;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4); // <<
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(['XML' => $request_xml]));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

the very first issue  in the option `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` you are sending your xml parameter as a string, while the server/api needs a normal POST request with one parameter named as `XML` and holds the xml data as a string

the other issue is that your `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` option you set is making troubleshot with the other side , so using the `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0` (4) option has fixed it;

Comment: Hi Sir Thank you for still answering but I'm still getting "''" response after outputting $result.

Comment: Thank you Sir. It was working after all. I need to work on my skills a lot.